# Reinstalling the app shows useless pushnotification GCM

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented push notification (GCM) in my application everything works great, however, when i uninstall the app and install it again shows me the push notification with no message in it. I dont know why this push notification is coming every time i install the application.

Below is my GCM code i thing the issue is at "sendNotification(message, "", "");"  Its showing me nullpointer exception.

Thank you in advance.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging
                .getInstance(context);
        ctx = context;
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        wl.acquire();
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(
                    "Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString(), "", "");
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + intent.getExtras().toString(), "", "");
        } else {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            String message = extras.getString("message");
            System.out.println("message " + message);
            Log.i("message", "" + message);
            //Do parsing here:
            sendNotification(message, "", "");
        }
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK); 
        wl.release();
    }

    // Put the GCM message into a notification and post it.
    private void sendNotification(String msg, String lati, String longi) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ListViewItems.class);


        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, i,
                0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                ctx).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smallscreen_logo)
                .setContentTitle("Promo Fusion")
                // .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                // .bigText(msg));
                .setContentText(msg);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        // FOR SOUND..
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(ctx, notification);
        r.play();

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
        02-10 21:26:54.910: I/System.out(30141): regid
    02-10 21:26:54.918: I/System.out(30141): sender id348234955373
    02-10 21:26:55.363: D/OpenGLRenderer(30141): Flushing caches (mode 0)
    02-10 21:26:56.472: I/System.out(30141): message null
    02-10 21:26:56.472: I/message(30141): null
    02-10 21:26:59.332: D/OpenGLRenderer(30141): Flushing caches (mode 0)
    02-10 21:26:59.718: D/OpenGLRenderer(30141): Flushing caches (mode 1)
    02-10 21:26:59.796: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(30141): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    02-10 21:27:01.882: D/PullToRefresh(30141): Setting Padding. L: 0, T: 0, R: 0, B: 0
    02-10 21:27:01.882: D/PullToRefresh(30141): First Visible: 0. Visible Count: 0. Total Items:0
    02-10 21:27:01.910: D/AndroidRuntime(30141): Shutting down VM
    02-10 21:27:01.910: W/dalvikvm(30141): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a421f8)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.promocloud.promofusion/com.promocloud.promofusion.ListViewItems}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.promocloud.promofusion.ListViewItems.onCreate(ListViewItems.java:140)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    02-10 21:27:02.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Why have you added the null pointer exception tag? This isn't referred to in your question.  Perhaps you can add some more detail to the question, because that's entirely different to something with "no message in it".

Comment: Could you show us some code? Where are you generating your notification and whereare you registering your device for gcm?

Comment: I guess because you have some code "showing" a push notification... can we see some of that?

Comment: @Poldie Thank you very much for replying, i had added null pointer, because when i click on that blank notification it shows me nullpointer exception here.

Comment: @A.S. I have updated my question with the code. Thank you for replying.

Comment: try to check if ` String message = extras.getString("message");` is empty

Comment: @A.S. I tried, no luck..!! :(

Comment: Can you post the logcat. It might be that you're mis-reading it. It's possible that sendNotification is being called and the null exception is within that function.